# How do I let another user add photos to my Google Photos album?

Tags: google-photos

I've got a Google Photos album which I've shared with other users via the *Get shareable link* feature. I'd like them to be able to add photos to this album. How do I do that?

P.S. I've googled for an answer, but find the various apparently out-of-date documentation for Google Photos, Google Plus, Google Picasa very confusing and not applicable. I'm hoping someone who understands it all better than me can give me a straight answer!

Comment: Shareable albums was recently announced by Google and should be coming to the Photos app soon.